# How to set pre-selected value in Yii2 Dropdownlist

Tags: drop-down-menu, yii2

Here i like to set preselected value in yii2 dropdownlist,

this is my dropdownlist, how i can set preselect value in this

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'tpa_email')->dropDownList(
                ArrayHelper::map(Approvaldetails::find()->all(),'id','tpa_email'),
                ['prompt' => 'Select Tpa Email..'])
            ?>
```

becoz everytime while updating the form , value getting reset.

Answer (score 2):

The value of `$model->tpa_email` will be used to select the value from the list items. So make sure that `$model->tpa_email` contains the key of the value you want to have selected.

Comment: actually problem is in my form i have many dropdown list, while creating form its working perfectly, but while updating the same form selected values getting reset and that makes me select again, i don't know what to do

Answer (score 0):

As jagsler said you just have to set the key of the dropdown value to model. Try following in your controller:

```
$model->tpa_email = $key;
```

Where `$key` will be the key of the preselected option you want to set.

Comment: How it's different from @jagsler's answer?

Comment: I have a form , in that there are many dropdownlist, while creating new i used to select values from dropdownlist and save that, its working perfectly. but while am updating the same form, the selected values get changed and again dropdownlist showing me select tpa_email [prompt],

Comment: i dont know what to do

Comment: @KalaiS You need to add such details to your question instead of comments. In current formulation the problem is solved.

Comment: still i didn't get any solution